# JSON undefined response from array and syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've just started learning basic html/css/js and am trying to build a site that takes a JSON file, parses it and builds a part of a site.

The script that I am using to parse right now is:

```
function getHighlights(){
var highlightsJSON = "highlights.json";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
    var myArr = JSON.parse(response);
    document.getElementById("highlights-container").innerHTML = myArr[0].src;
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", highlightsJSON, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

The JSON file that I am trying to parse is:

```
[
{
    "src": "sample.jpg",
    "title": "Day 1: Short Title",
    "desc": "desc"
},

{
    "src": "sample.jpg",
    "title": "Day 2: Longer title With More Words",
    "desc": "desc"
},

{
    "src": "sample.jpg",
    "title": "Day 3: Medium title Words",
    "desc": "desc"
}
]
```

What I know right now:
1) the script appears to work, I can replace everything in the given id with whatever I type after the page finishes loading (running the script using body onload..). 
2) When I do alert(myArr);, a correct looking parsed json text seems to show up.

However...

1) I get some JSON syntax error from firefox saying:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error
>   Location: file: (removed description)
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

2)
From my understanding, JSON files can start with a block paren, and I should be able to access it using myArr[i], where i could be 0,1,2 in my example. When I tried doing myArr[i].src; or any of those, it always yields undefined, no matter what I do.

**My attempts:**

*Regarding problem 1:*
I have thought that it could be /n or some characters messing it up, but it parse(..) seems to have gotten rid of those characters when I compared it to my response variable. I have also used .replace(..) but that also did not do anything (which isn't too much of a surprise to me, since I didn't find any such /n characters when I printed myArr compared to response). I also checked the JSON syntax validity using the site, and it seemed to be ok..

*Regarding problem 2:*
I am not sure at all why I can't access any of my values. Any insight into why myArr[0].src or similar may not be working would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to stick to basic, fundamental JS and not use JQuery AJAX ... etc, as I've literally just begun learning this.

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: `this.responseText` is already a string - don't try to `stringify` it, that won't work. Just do `var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText)`

Comment: oh my god that was it.......thank you so much, been just spinning my wheels for like the last hour and half over this.. I did that because previously I kept getting another error saying that I needed double quotes (which I'm not sure what I changed but I don't get that anymore, even after removing stringify)..  I'm still getting that strange error from firefox about wrong syntax, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code
 No Need of `var response = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);` This is an extra line of code. just convert response text to json like v`ar response = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);`

```
function getHighlights(){
var highlightsJSON = "highlights.json";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //var response = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    document.getElementById("highlights-container").innerHTML = myArr[0].src;
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", highlightsJSON, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: @user539820 try this answer, hope this will help you

Comment: yes! thank you! I can get the values from the array now! Thanks! Do you see anything wrong with the JSON file? There is an XMLparsing syntax error. But I seem to be able to get the objects just fine..